# Move a range of cells from a row to another google sheet and delete it

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I got the following code working but not as I would like to.

```
function onEdit(event) {
 
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var r = event.source.getActiveRange();
  if(s.getName() == "Listed" && r.getColumn() == 21 && r.getValue() == "yes") {
    var row = r.getRow();
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sold");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
    s.deleteRow(row);
  }
}
```

I have 2 sheets, one for Items listed, and one for items sold. I need to delete a row in "Listed" when the column 21 says "yes" and paste it in my "Sold" sheet.

Is there a way to copy and paste only a range of cells from "Listed" to "Sold" but to delete the whole row ?

Comment: Hi! Did my answer worked for you ?

Answer (score 0):

### Explanation:

- Your goal is to copy only a subset of the edit row and paste it to
  the destination sheet and then delete that row in the source sheet.
- The following script will copy only the first 10 columns of that row. Adjust `const numColumns = 10` to your needs.

---

### Solution:

```
function onEdit(e) {
 
  const ss = e.source;
  const s = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  const row = e.range.getRow();
  const col = e.range.getColumn();
  const targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sold");
  const numColumns = 10;

  if(s.getName() == "Listed" && col == 21 && e.range.getValue() == "yes") {
    
    const s_range = s.getRange(row,1,1,numColumns);
    const s_values = s_range.getValues();
    s.deleteRow(row);
    targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1,s_values.length,s_values[0].length).setValues(s_values);
   
  }
}
```